# Magic Enter in BASH like ZSH

Tags: bash

How can I set magic enter in bash like zsh in oh-my-zsh? I have tried:

```
bind '"\C-m":"ls\n"'
```

But this makes bash unusable

Comment: What is "magic enter"?

Comment: its a ohmyzsh plugin. When magic enter is enabled, you can automate commands by typing enter.Like: if i set "ls" as magic-enter command, i dont have to type "ls" every time . What i need to do is just pressing enter...